# Custom User Control GUI Redraw

Tags: c#, user-interface, user-controls

I have a custom User Control I made and I'm having trouble triggering a refresh on the onPaint function

```
public void addColor(ColorTypes.RGB rgb)
{
    _color_list.Add(rgb);
    this.Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    // Call the OnPaint method of the base class.
    base.OnPaint(pe);

    Graphics g = pe.Graphics;

    Size rect_size = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width / _color_list.Count, this.ClientSize.Height);
    int count = 0;
    foreach (ColorTypes.RGB rgb in _color_list)
    {
        Point p = new Point(count * rect_size.Width, 0);
        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(ColorTypes.RGBtoColor(rgb));
        g.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(p, rect_size));
        myBrush.Dispose();
        count++;
    }
}
```

addColor is called by the parent of this object. When the _color_list is updated, I want to OnPaint function to trigger again and redraw the graphic with the new color.

EDIT: Solved it.

In my case, the parent object was doing this on construction:

```
        myUserControl= new myControl();
        myUserControl.Show();
```

Which was hijacking the object from the proper construction in the .Designer.cs file:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.myUserControl= new myControl();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    ...
```

Comment: The code you posted is fine (as in correct, but not fine as in sufficient to explain the problem). You need only call `Invalidate()`, not `Update()` (but the latter doesn't really hurt anything here). So the problem is in the code you didn't post. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer. You can then get upvotes for it, and you can even mark it as the accepted answer.